# maven plugin sonarqube doesn't resolve it's dependencies

Tags: maven, sonarqube

When I try to run the mvn sonar:sonar target maven are unable to run sonar, here is the relevant part of the mvn output:

```
[INFO] Execute: org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6:sonar
[WARNING] While downloading javax.xml:jaxrpc:1.1
  This artifact has been relocated to javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:1.1.


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Can not execute Sonar

Embedded error: Unable to load the mojo 'org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6:sonar' in the plugin 'org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/dependency/tree/DependencyTreeBuilder;
```

org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeBuilder

It seems like maven doesn't download the required dependency for some reason.

I have a local nexus configured that contains the jar, but i get the same result regardless if I have that profile active in my settings.xml or not.

How should I configure maven in order for it to try to download the dependency?

Comment: maven version is 2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by running:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -U
```

Apparently there was some corruption in the .m2 directory.